# Does this sound like a power supply issue?

Tags: power-supply, crash, reboot

On my custom built computer, I've had a issue where it randomly reboots on me. No blue-screen, just black then it reboots, almost like if you kill the power.

I bought a UPS, thinking it might be house electricity that was unstable. Still having the problems.

Today it died on me but this time it didn't reboot. Pressing the power button a few times didn't do anything. Checking the power connections, I moved the power cable to another outlet port (these are battery backup and surge protection outlets on the UPS). It rebooted.

A little while later, I tried using the original outlet port to charge my phone. It works fine.

I'm thinking of getting a EVGA or Corsair 750W Bronze and hope that helps.

P.S. Or maybe I'm haunted. The other day, the overhead lamp bulbs died on me.

Comment: How old is your PC? What is your PC configuration and what is the  Wattage  rating of your current power supply? Random reboots may also be a result of faulty motherboard.

Comment: Less than a year old. Sentey XPP725-HS Xplus Power Supply 725W powering my 4790K CPU and GTX 950 GPU.  Fatal1ty Z97 Killer Mobo.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a heat problem or a power supply problem.  Either bad power supply or power supply does not provide enough capacity for your system.  If you hadn't used a UPS, I'd suspect dirty power (brown outs) could be the cause.

Is the system on, under load for a long time before the reset happens?  Does it feel warm near the processor?  (Don't burn yourself, don't touch anything, just feel the air near the processor).  These are heat symptoms.  Look in bios settings for any kind of bios based heat triggered shutoff.  Consider temperature monitoring software.

If you have access to a known good power supply, you could try it.  Or if you can afford a replacement.

Comment: I've checked CPUID HWMonitor and the CPU cores are about mid 80F on idle. Doesn't seem like heat issue.

Comment: That leaves insufficient power supply and faulty power supply.